# why can't i use useState in react

Tags: react-hooks

When I want to use useState, one of the hooks structures, in react, he gets angry with me `const [apple, setApple] = useState(false)`. I have never encountered such a problem before. Could there be a place I overlooked?[image]

Comment: try capitalizing component name i.e Apple

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803862/i-get-an-error-when-using-reactjs-usestate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write your hook inside of a component, when you start the name of component with Lowercase letters, it defines as a normal function not a component, change it to Capital letters...

```
import React from "react"

export default function Apple(props) {

    const [apple, setApple] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
          YOUR_CONTENT
        </div>
    )
}
```